# Documentation on Angular Material $mdDialog.finally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

From the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.dialog/service/$mdDialog), dialog boxes in Angular Material have a signature like so:

```
function showAlert() {
  alert = $mdDialog.alert()
    .title('Attention, ' + $scope.userName)
    .content('This is an example of how easy dialogs can be!')
    .ok('Close');
  $mdDialog
      .show( alert )
      .finally(function() {
        alert = undefined;
      });
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on `.finally`. It appears to be a callback function from what I can gather, though the documentation is oddly lacking any info.

Should I assume it is a normal callback function—and why is the documentation on it lacking—is this simply such standard directive syntax that this is assumed to be the way to deal with callbacks, like `.then`?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: it returns a promise, research angular promises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$mdDialog.show()` returns a promise. `finally` is an action that you take on completion of a promise, regardless of if it was resolved or rejected. Typically, `finally` is used to handle whatever cleanup should be done once the promise has completed (just like it does here by clearing the `alert` variable).

Angular uses the `q` library to handle promises, so you can find information on the `finally()` method at the [Q API Reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback)